# A good looking navigation menu, only one task remaining

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have designed a beautiful menu and need help adding a feature. My problem is that I want the collection hover state to persist when hovering over a sub menu.

HTML

```
<div class="navi">
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="#" title="Women">Women</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Men</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Junior</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Accessories</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Collections</a>
                    <ul class='children'>
                        <li><a href="#" style="background-image: none; font-weight: bold;">Year</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">2014</a> <span class="nav-arrow">&#9656;</span>
                            <ul class='children'>
                                <li><a href="#" style="background-image: none;">SUMMER</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" style="background-image: none;">AUTUMN</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" style="background-image: none;">WINTER</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" style="background-image: none;">SPRING</a></li>

                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="">2013</a><span class="nav-arrow">&#9656;</span>
                            <ul class='children'>
                                <li><a href="#" style="background-image: none;">SUMMER</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" style="background-image: none;">AUTUMN</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" style="background-image: none;">WINTER</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" style="background-image: none;">SPRING</a></li>

                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="">2012</a><span class="nav-arrow">&#9656;</span>
                            <ul class='children'>
                                <li><a href="#" style="background-image: none;">SUMMER</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" style="background-image: none;">AUTUMN</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" style="background-image: none;">WINTER</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" style="background-image: none;">SPRING</a></li>

                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="">2011</a> <span class="nav-arrow">&#9656;</span>
                            <ul class='children'>
                                <li><a href="#" style="background-image: none;">SUMMER</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" style="background-image: none;">AUTUMN</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" style="background-image: none;">WINTER</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" style="background-image: none;">SPRING</a></li>

                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="sale"><a href="#">Sale</a></li>
                <li class="last"><a href='#'>MY ACCOUNT</a></li>
            </ul>
            <br style="clear: both;" />
        </div>


    </div>
```

CSS

```
.navi {
        width:100%;
        border-bottom:5px solid #000;
        height:50px;
        margin-bottom:10px;
        padding:0;
    }

    .menu {
        width:100%;
        padding:0;
        margin:0;

    }
    .menu, .menu ul {
        display: block;
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .menu li {
        font-family:Open Sans;
        border: 0 none;
        display: block;
        float: left;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 5;
        text-transform:uppercase;
        font-family:Open Sans;
        font-weight:bold;

    }
    .menu li a{
    font-size:14px;}
    .menu li:hover {
        white-space: normal;
        z-index: 100;
    }
    .menu li li {
        float: none;
    }
    .menu ul {
        left: 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
        z-index: 10;
    }
    .menu li:hover > ul {
        top: 100%;
        visibility: visible;
    }
    .menu li li:hover > ul {
        left: 100%;
        top: 0;
    }
    .menu:after, .menu ul:after {
        clear: both;
        content: ".";
        display: block;
        height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    .menu, .menu ul {
        min-height: 0;
    }
    .menu ul {
        margin: -10px 0 0 -30px;
        padding: 10px 30px 30px;
    }
    .menu ul ul {
        margin: -30px 0 0 -10px;
        padding: 30px 30px 30px 10px;
    }
    .menu ul li a:hover, .menu li li a:hover {
        color: #484848;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .menu ul {
        min-width: 15em;
        width: auto;    
    }
    .menu a.arrow {
        background: url(img/arrow.gif) no-repeat right center;
    }
    .menu ul a.arrow {
        background: url(img/right.gif) no-repeat 97% center;
    }
    .menu .menuRight {
        float: right;
        margin-right: 0px;
    }

    .menu a {
        font-family:Open Sans;
        color: #314350;
        display: block;
        height:50px;
        line-height:50px;
        margin: 0 0px 0 0;
        padding: 0 1em;
        position: relative;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size:18px;

    }
    .menu a:hover {
        background-color: #1c2b36;
        color: #ffffff;
        box-shadow:#000 0 0 0, inset #3cc0c4 0 -5px 0;
    }
    .menu .current_page_item a {
        background-color:#1c2b36;
        color: #ffffff;
        box-shadow:#000 0 0 0, inset #3cc0c4 0 -5px 0;
    }
    .menu li li {

        background:#DFDFDF;

        color: #000;
        filter: none;
        width: auto;
    }
    .menu li li a {
        background-position: 50% 50%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;

        color: #000;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: 400;
        height: 40px;
        line-height: 40px;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        text-shadow: none;
        white-space: nowrap;
        width: auto;
    }
    .menu li li a:hover {
        background:#E5E4E4;
        box-shadow:none;    
    }
    .menu ul > li + li {
        border-top: 0 none;
    }
    .menu li li:hover > ul {
        left: 100%;
        top: 0;
    }
    .menu > li:first-child > a {
        border-left: medium none;
    }
    .menu > li:first-child > a, .menu li + li + li li:first-child > a {
    }
    .menu ul.children a, .menu .current_page_ancestor, .menu .current_page_ancestor ul a {
        background: none;
        filter: none;

    }
    .menu ul.children a{background:url(images/arrow.png) no-repeat 93% 70%;}
    .menu ul.children a:hover{background:url(images/arrow.png) no-repeat 93% 70% #999;}
    ul.sub-menu .current_page_item a {
        background:none;
    }

    .nav-arrow {

        position:absolute;
        top:8px;
        right: 4px;
    }

    li.last {
    float:right;
    padding-left:60px;

    }
    li.sale a {
    color:#F05050;

    }
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D5ezv/)

Comment: Nice menu! Could you clarify a bit more? I'm not sure I understand. Yo want the "COLLECTION" to remain styled black when someone is hovering over one of its child elements?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution is pretty simple.  Whenever you have a:hover replace it with li:hover > a.  The reason it needs to be this way is because whenever you are hovering over the nested list item you automatically hover over its list item ancestor, which will automatically make the ancestor hovered also, thereby invoking the :hover state on it.

By the way, in my book, "Functional CSS," which is still available for free on amazon, I build a complex navigation menu that is displayed differently depending on the browser space.  Your menu looks good, but some elements still need tweaking.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aQ9h5/

```
replace a:hover with li:hover > a
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to target your elements a little differently with CSS.

Currently, you are decorating the menu by targeting each menu *anchor* hover state like this:

```
 .menu a:hover {
       /* menu item styles here */
}
```

Therefore when the user hovers over the parent link, to access the menu items they immediately move the mouse *out* of it. You need to be applying the `:hover` state to the parent element that envelopes the entire menu item *and* it's children. In this case, `.menu li`.

And so we don't affect *all* the child elements (meaning the nested lists within), you can [target direct children](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) using the selector `>`

```
.menu > li:hover > a {
    /* menu styles here*/
}
```

Here it is again targeting the nested list items within the main menu items:

```
.menu ul.children > li:hover > a {
     /* nested menu item styles */
}
```

Or alternately, you could target the same items like this:

```
.menu li > ul > li:hover > a
```

Here's an **[example of it working](http://jsfiddle.net/D5ezv/)**.